# Bootstrap modal working with Firefox but not in Chrome

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal, papaparse

This is my code, it closes a modal after pressing a button, opens another one right after and executes a parsing function:

```
$('#BtnUpCsv').on('click', function (e) {
      $('#csvModal').modal('hide');
      $('#pBarModal').modal('show');
      Papa.parse(document.getElementById('csvinput').files[0], {...
```

In Firefox it works as intended but in Chrome the first modal won't close immediatly after the function is called and the parsing starts as it has some weird priority over the first two functions. After the parse is over the `csvModal` is closed and the `pBarModal` appears.
I already tried adding a `setTimeout` but it messes with the parsing function.

Any idea why this happens?

EDIT: entire function

```
Papa.parse(document.getElementById('csvinput').files[0], {
        header: true,
        skipEmptyLines: true,
        complete: function(results) {
          pBarMax = results.data.length - 1;
          results.data.forEach(function (data) {
            const csvPcode = data.pcode;
            const csvAntiOx = data.AntiOx;
            const csvCalories = data.Calories;
            const csvCarbs = data.Carbs;
            const csvFats = data.Fats;
            const csvFibers = data.Fibers;
            const csvLipides = data.Lipides;
            const csvProteins = data.Proteins;
            const csvSat_fats = data.Sat_fats;
            const csvSodium = data.Sodium;
            const csvSugars = data.Sugars;

            //Update progress bar
            pBarPerc = ((iPbar/PbarMax) * 100).toFixed();
            $('#progressBar').text(+ pBarPerc + '%');
            $('#progressBar').attr('style','width:' + pBarPerc + '%');
            //console.log(pBarPerc);

            //Rpc requests
            $.ajax({
              type: 'POST',
              url: '../contents/cbk-data-process.php',
              async: false,
              data: {
                method: 'prod-variable-saveby-name',
                node: <?php echo $node ?>,
                pcode: csvPcode,
                objectname: 'AntiOx',
                value: csvAntiOx
              },
              dataType: 'json'
            } );

            $.ajax({
              type: 'POST',
              url: '../contents/cbk-data-process.php',
              async: false,
              data: {
                method: 'prod-variable-saveby-name',
                node: <?php echo $node ?>,
                pcode: csvPcode,
                objectname: 'Calories',
                value: csvCalories
              },
              dataType: 'json'
            } );

            $.ajax({
              type: 'POST',
              url: '../contents/cbk-data-process.php',
              async: false,
              data: {
                method: 'prod-variable-saveby-name',
                node: <?php echo $node ?>,
                pcode: csvPcode,
                objectname: 'Carbs',
                value: csvCarbs
              },
              dataType: 'json'
            } );

            $.ajax({
              type: 'POST',
              url: '../contents/cbk-data-process.php',
              async: false,
              data: {
                method: 'prod-variable-saveby-name',
                node: <?php echo $node ?>,
                pcode: csvPcode,
                objectname: 'Fats',
                value: csvFats
              },
              dataType: 'json'
            } );

            $.ajax({
              type: 'POST',
              url: '../contents/cbk-data-process.php',
              async: false,
              data: {
                method: 'prod-variable-saveby-name',
                node: <?php echo $node ?>,
                pcode: csvPcode,
                objectname: 'Fibers',
                value: csvFibers
              },
              dataType: 'json'
            } );

            $.ajax({
              type: 'POST',
              url: '../contents/cbk-data-process.php',
              async: false,
              data: {
                method: 'prod-variable-saveby-name',
                node: <?php echo $node ?>,
                pcode: csvPcode,
                objectname: 'Lipides',
                value: csvLipides
              },
              dataType: 'json'
            } );

            $.ajax({
              type: 'POST',
              url: '../contents/cbk-data-process.php',
              async: false,
              data: {
                method: 'prod-variable-saveby-name',
                node: <?php echo $node ?>,
                pcode: csvPcode,
                objectname: 'Proteins',
                value: csvProteins
              },
              dataType: 'json'
            } );

            $.ajax({
              type: 'POST',
              url: '../contents/cbk-data-process.php',
              async: false,
              data: {
                method: 'prod-variable-saveby-name',
                node: <?php echo $node ?>,
                pcode: csvPcode,
                objectname: 'Sat_fats',
                value: csvSat_fats
              },
              dataType: 'json'
            } );

            $.ajax({
              type: 'POST',
              url: '../contents/cbk-data-process.php',
              async: false,
              data: {
                method: 'prod-variable-saveby-name',
                node: <?php echo $node ?>,
                pcode: csvPcode,
                objectname: 'Sodium',
                value: csvSodium
              },
              dataType: 'json'
            } );

            $.ajax({
              type: 'POST',
              url: '../contents/cbk-data-process.php',
              async: false,
              data: {
                method: 'prod-variable-saveby-name',
                node: <?php echo $node ?>,
                pcode: csvPcode,
                objectname: 'Sugars',
                value: csvSugars
              },
              dataType: 'json'
            } );
            iPbar++;
          } );
          //Reset progress bar on completition and modal when hidden
          let PbarResult = $('#pBarModalLabel').text('Completed, ' + results.data.length + ' records updated');
          pBarMax = 0;
          pBarPerc = 0;
          $('#tbl-pcodes').DataTable().ajax.reload();
          setTimeout(function() {$('#pBarModal').modal('hide');}, 2000);
          setTimeout(function() {$('#pBarModalLabel').text('Processing... please wait');}, 2500);
        }
      } );
    } );
```

Comment: We need to see more of your code to understand the problem. Is there something in the parsing function that requires the modal to be shown?

Comment: @Conman_123 No, the modal is hidden but the input file is still there and it can be fetched by the function. After a few modifications I was able to set a timeout to the parser, the first modal now closes and the second one appears. The progress bar works but it doesn't update until the parsering is over...

Answer (score 0):

Ok I think I understand your problem now. Here is a JSFiddle I created to recreate the problem, and to show how the solution works:
https://jsfiddle.net/rn3y1qgd/7/

The reason it seems like your parsing function is taking "priority" over the modals hiding and showing is because the modal functions are asynchronous. Basically this means when you call them, it won't start updating the html (to hide/show the modals) until after all the code has finished running. This means it has to wait for your parsing function to finish before it shows/hides the modals.

The solution is to wait for the modal to be shown **before** calling the parsing function. In the fiddle this is the relevant part:

```js
$("#testbtnSolution").click(function() {
    $("#exampleModal").modal('hide');   
    $("#exampleModal2").one('shown.bs.modal', function() {
      longExecutingFunction(2000);
      alert("processing done");
    }).modal('show');  
});
```

In this code we register an event handler that runs on `shown.bs.modal`. Once the modal has finished showing, it will then run your processing function.